# Styled browser console.log with line breaks

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, console.log

In google chrome, I'm trying to add colors to console.logs using css, but I'm facing a problem with line breaks.

in a simple console log, `\n` works just fine:
[image]

but it somehow gets ignored when I add styles:
[image]

do you know why this is happening? and how I can solve it without making several calls to console.log?

Comment: which version of chrome are you using ? I tried `console.log('%c%s%c \n b', 'color: blue', 'a', '')` and it works (chrome 69.0.3497.100 )

Comment: There was a bug in several recent versions of Chrome but it's fixed in 68, see https://crbug.com/810581.

Comment: Version 66.0.3359.181 on Ubuntu linux 18.04. Thanks, I'll try on another version. curious to know if this is a bug or desired behaviour though

Comment: thanks for the link @wOxxOm

Comment: @ben - So am I. What made a difference was opening my blasted eyes and reading the format string correctly. **:-)** (Was kinda hoping you hadn't seen the comment before I deleted it.)